# Sort An Array in Decresing Order - Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am trying to solve this exercise but I am facing some problems while trying to do so. In logical terms, I think that I am thinking right. Could you take a look at my code please and try to help me?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;


public class exercicio_4_alapata {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [] Array_numal;
        Array_numal = new int [100];

        int [] ArrayOrdenado;
        ArrayOrdenado = new int [100];

        int posicao_array;
        int posicao_array2 = 0;

        for (posicao_array = 0; posicao_array < Array_numal.length; posicao_array ++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            Array_numal [posicao_array] = rand.nextInt(101);
        }

        int maior = Array_numal [0];


        while (maior != ArrayOrdenado[99]) {

            for (posicao_array2 = 0; posicao_array2 == 99; posicao_array2 ++) {

                for (posicao_array = 0; posicao_array < Array_numal.length; posicao_array ++) {

                    if ((Array_numal[posicao_array] > maior) && (maior < ArrayOrdenado [posicao_array2 - 1])) {
                        maior = ArrayOrdenado [posicao_array2];
                    } 
                }
            }
        }


        for (posicao_array2 = 0; posicao_array2 < ArrayOrdenado.length; posicao_array2 ++) {
            System.out.println(ArrayOrdenado[posicao_array2]);
        }      

    }
}
```

Comment: Which problems are you facing?

Comment: `(posicao_array2 = 0; posicao_array2 == 99; posicao_array2++)`? outer for loop will never run and outer while will never break.

Comment: well, when i print out the second array I ahve created with the elements ordered in decreasing order it only prints zeros... what would you change in terms of logic?

Comment: There are three nested loops in your program. Rethink and reprogram.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use collections... if I could the exercise would be automatically solved

Comment: In term of logic I will try to use another algorithme cause the one you are using seams to be very ineficient in term of performance. Try a merge sort http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html. Then you will have a sorted array in O(nlogn) then you can go through from the tail to the head (decreasing order) or from head to the tail (increasing order). You can as well change the algorithme to get directly the array sorted by decreasing order.

Comment: how do I copy only one element of the array to the other?

Comment: like this: ArrayOrdenado [posicao_array2] = Array_numal[posicao_array];

Comment: I have done that...

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use Arrays.sort(T[] a, Comparator c)):

```
Arrays.sort(a, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

Comment: Being an exercise, I don't think this is what his teacher is looking for

Comment: I have already done the exercise using collections... but I am trying to do it in another way... and avoiding collections... what do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: First of all,  `for (posicao_array2 = 0; posicao_array2 == 99; posicao_array2 ++)` will never work. Use `<=` instead of `==`. As it is now, that loop will never run

Comment: If you want people writing code for you, there's plenty of sorting algorithms on the net... just google for them

Comment: I dont it... I want help... thats why I am here... I dont want other people to code for me otherwise I would be solving this problem in the way i am

Comment: If you want to learn how to solve your problem. You can try to implement by yourself some well known algorithme: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Efficient_sorts.